# Using Laravel pagination with Bootstrap-vue pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination, bootstrap-vue

Is it possible to use [**Laravel** pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination) with [**Bootstrap-vue** pagination](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/pagination-nav) ?

I'm trying this:

```
<b-pagination-nav :link-gen="linkGen"></b-pagination-nav>
```

Default method of Bootstrap-vue:

```
linkGen (pageNum) {
  return `${pageNum}`
}
```

But it doesn't seem possible to set `first`/`prev`/`next`/`last` pages links that **Laravel** sends me:

```
current_page: (...)
data: (...)
first_page_url: (...)
from: (...)
last_page: (...)
last_page_url: (...)
next_page_url: (...)
path: (...)
per_page: (...)
prev_page_url: (...)
to: (...)
total: (...)
```

Comment: The first, last, next, prev buttons will use `linkGen` function to generate the link rendered in those buttons.

Comment: But these links won’t have the GET parameters necessary to retrieve data for other pages. Can I force it somehow to use links provided by Laravel links with my GET parameters ?

Comment: Currently, no... But will look into a way to pass the button type the link is being requested for, which will then be passed to the `linkGen` function. Although if the URL doesn't match the URL for the current page, the auto-detection of the current page may not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able make b-pagination-nav work with Laravel's pagination informations.

```html
<b-pagination-nav 
    @input="loadPage"
    :link-gen="linkGen" 
    :number-of-pages="laravelData.last_page"
    :limit="20"
    use-router></b-pagination-nav>
```

@input works when the user changes the page in the URL too.

```js
data(){
    return {
      companies: null
      laravelData: null //used for pagination
    }
},

mounted(){
    this.loadPage(1);
},

methods: {
    loadPage(page){
      http.get('/companies?page=' + page)
      .then(data => {
        this.companies = data.data
        this.laravelData = data
      })
    },

    linkGen(pageNum) {
      return { path: `/companies?pages=${pageNum}` }
    }
}
```